# Snakemake specify a new wildcard in a new rule

Tags: wildcard, snakemake

I have input files:

```
Bob_1.fastq.gz
Bob_2.fastq.gz
Bob_3.fastq.gz
Bob_4.fastq.gz
Ron_1.fastq.gz
Ron_2.fastq.gz
Ron_3.fastq.gz
Ron_4.fastq.gz
```

I am running demultiplexing and trimming steps in one snakefile, like this:

```
workdir: "/path/to/dir/"
(SAMPLES,) =glob_wildcards('/path/to/dir/raw/{sample}.fastq.gz')

rule all:
    input:
        expand("demulptiplex/{sample}.fastq.gz", sample=SAMPLES),
        expand("trimmed/{sample}.trimmed.fastq.gz", sample=SAMPLES)

rule sabre:
    input:
        infile="/path/to/dir/raw/{sample}.fastq.gz",
        barcodefile= "files/{sample}.txt"
    output:
        unknownfile=temp("demulptiplex/unknown_barcode_{sample}.fastq.gz"),
    shell:
        """
        /Tools/sabre-master2/sabre se -f {input.infile} -b {input.barcodefile} -u {output.unknownfile}
        """

rule trimmomatic_se:
    input:
        r="{sample}.fastq.gz"
    output:
        r="trimmed/{sample}.trimmed.fastq.gz"
    threads: 10
    shell:
        """java -jar /Tools/Trimmomatic-0.36/trimmomatic-0.36.jar SE -threads {threads} {input.r} {output.r} ILLUMINACLIP:/Tools/Trimmomatic-0.36/adapters/TruSeq3-SE.fa:2:30:10 LEADING:3 TRAILING:3 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:15 MINLEN:36"""
```

The demultiplex output files are like this:

```
Bob_1_CL1.fastq.gz.... Bob_1_CL345.fastq.gz
Bob_2_CL1.fastq.gz.... Bob_1_CL248.fastq.gz
Ron_1_dad1.fastq.gz... Ron_1_dad67.fastq.gz
```

and so on

So,if I do not specify the `demultiplex` output file the program would create it by itself. My problem is how to specify/introduce a new `wildcard` from the output of the previous rule in the next trimming step, as the `wildcards` are different from initial `sample` now.

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards just need to be consistent in a rule, not across the workflow.  The issue here is that you have a rule generating 'unknown' outputs that you need to process further.  For that you need to use [checkpoints](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution).

Read through the second block of code about aggregating.  Your checkpoint will be demultiplexing and if you don't have any other steps, `all` will be your aggregate step that calls `checkpoints.demultiplex.get`.  If you search for checkpoint on stackoverflow you will find lots of examples; it's a hard feature to use at first!